# Android - How do I get location updates in the background in a service

Tags: android, kotlin, android-service, android-location

I need to access location in the background when my app is running.

I successfully received location updates when my main activity implemented `android.location.LocationListener`

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    val locationManager = getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
    val criteria = Criteria()
    val provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false)
    val location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider)

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 5000, 20f, this)
    setLocation(location)
} else {
    /* ... */
}
```

However I attempted to add this code to a new service class (implementing both `android.app.Service` and `android.location.LocationListener`), and the `onLocationChanged` function is only firing when the app is in view.

I believe this problem could be one of the following:

1. I think I read somewhere that I have to manually create a new thread inside the service so that it does not run on the same thread as the main activity. This could be the issue, but I haven't a clue how to do this. I'm new to android development and Kotlin.
2. I think I read somewhere that the location permissions I currently request aren't enough when accessing location in the background, but can't find out what to change.
3. I saw a solution somewhere where they create a timer that runs every few seconds and manually requests the last location from the location manager. I haven't tested this, but if it does work it doesn't satisfy my needs. The `requestLocationUpdates` allows me to configure both a minimum time and minimum distance. Of course I could manually add in a distance check, but this could affect battery life and performance.

How do I fix this problem?

(I can probably change any Java code to Kotlin if anyone is not familiar with Kotlin)

---

**Edit 1**

- My service is definitely running, as the location updates are received in the foreground
- Here is the `onStartCommand` code for my service:

```
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startid: Int): Int {
    /* request location updates as above */
    return START_STICKY
}
```

- Here is how I start the service in my main activity:

```
val serviceIntent = Intent(applicationContext, OnTheFlyLandmarkService::class.java)
startService(serviceIntent)
```

---

**Edit 2**

4. I also read that I need to display a notification to let users know that my service is running in the background. I tried the following code but this did not help:

   ```
   val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
       .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.messageicon)
       .setContentTitle("My app")
       .setContentText("Accessing location in background...")
       .setAutoCancel(true)
       .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
       .build()

   with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(this)) {
       notify(id, notification)
   }
   ```

---

**Edit 3**

I tried what @Michael said: call `startForeground` inside the service and pass in the notification. This did not work, and I didn't even see a notification.

```
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startid: Int): Int {
    val notification = buildNotification("My app", "Accessing location in background...")
    startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID_SERVICE, notification)

    /* request location updates */
    return START_STICKY
}
```

Comment: Can you add the `Service` code you created? Is your `Service` started with run in foreground? Is it `Sticky`?

Comment: @madlymad I added code, it is a sticky service

Comment: Starting with Android 8.0, your app will only get a few location updates per hour if it is in the background. If that's not enough for you, then use a [foreground service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground) instead.

Comment: @Michael this did not work for me. Thanks for all of your help so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For using a `Service` that always runs you have some important things:

1. Add it to your manifest

```
    <manifest ... >
      ...
      <application ... >
          <service android:name=".ExampleService" />
          ...
      </application>
    </manifest>
```

2. Make it `START_STICKY` so as the system to restart it, in case it kills it.

```
    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        Toast.makeText(this, "service starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        // ...

        // If we get killed, after returning from here, restart
        return START_STICKY
    }
```

3. Start it in foreground this is required for any app that target Android 9 (API level 28). Otherwise you get a `SecurityException`. Plus the permission in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
```

4. To pass location data between your service and your activity you may also consider the binding mechanism. (details into the second link, *note that notification creation in the example is outdated without the channel*)

You already have the 1 and 2. So you have to do the 3.

Use a foreground notification in your Service `OnCreate` method.

```
val pendingIntent: PendingIntent =
        Intent(this, ExampleActivity::class.java).let { notificationIntent ->
            PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0)
        }

val notification: Notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.messageicon)
.setContentTitle("My app")
.setContentText("Accessing location in background...")
.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
.setAutoCancel(true)
.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
.build()

startForeground(ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification)
// Caution: The integer ID that you give to startForeground() must not be 0.
```

Check for more details the official documentation:

- https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services
- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service

Comment: The notification is not showing for some reason. Is `ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID` a special id? I just used id `0`. Is the intent necessary for the notification to appear?

Comment: According to documentation you can use anything else expept `0` because with `0` it will not appear ;)

Comment: Haha that worked thanks a million, I also needed to add the `FOREGROUND_SERVICE` permission.

Comment: Great! I also edit the post in order to be complete! xD